# An error occured to read the PNG file from file system on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda and will read some file from Lambda function.

A text file can be read, even though A png file can not be read. It seems to be kind of strange.
Does AWS lambda can not read the PNG file?

I did the following process:

1. In order to upload to AWS Lambda, archiving a project.

   ```
   $ ls -1
   index.js
   test.png
   test.txt


   $ cat index.js
   exports.handler = function(event, context) {
     var fs = require('fs');

     var path = __dirname + '/test.txt';

     fs.readFile(path, function(err, buffer) {
         console.log('err = ' + err);
         console.log(buffer.length);
         context.done();
     });
   }

   $ zip -r lambda.zip .
     adding: index.js (deflated 35%)
     adding: test.png (deflated 1%)
     adding: test.txt (stored 0%)
   ```
2. Upload an archive file to AWS Lambda and invoke the function.
3. Invoked result is successful.

   ```
   START RequestId: 2997ce37-2628-11e5-9e15-456a1ab0c0d0
   2015-07-09T10:49:24.660Z    2997ce37-2628-11e5-9e15-456a1ab0c0d0    err = null
   2015-07-09T10:49:24.661Z    2997ce37-2628-11e5-9e15-456a1ab0c0d0    5
   END RequestId: 2997ce37-2628-11e5-9e15-456a1ab0c0d0
   REPORT RequestId: 2997ce37-2628-11e5-9e15-456a1ab0c0d0  Duration: 123.68 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 9 MB
   ```
4. Cnahge reading file from test.txt to test.png.
5. Upload an archive file to AWS Lambda and invoke the function.
6. Invoked result is failure.

   ```
   START RequestId: d9d5b6ff-2627-11e5-92ff-85a0d38392ee
   2015-07-09T10:47:10.689Z    d9d5b6ff-2627-11e5-92ff-85a0d38392ee    err = Error: EACCES, open '/var/task/resource/test.png'
   END RequestId: d9d5b6ff-2627-11e5-92ff-85a0d38392ee
   REPORT RequestId: d9d5b6ff-2627-11e5-92ff-85a0d38392ee  Duration: 214.73 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 10 MB  
   Process exited before completing request
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are something wrong with the file permission.
Try `ls -l`

AWS Lambda use `v0.10.36`, indeed you can test locally.
For example, create a `test.js`, like below:

```
var handler = require('.').handler;
var ctx = {
  done: function () {
    console.log('Done');
  }
};
handler('', ctx);
```

For this scenario, you can simply use `test.js` as below:

```
  var fs = require('fs');

  var path = __dirname + '/test.png';

  fs.readFile(path, function(err, buffer) {
      console.log('err = ' + err);
      console.log(buffer.length);
      context.done();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. AWS Lambda is managed services such as Paas, so I can not execute `ls -l`...

Comment: @Nori I mean you can `ls -l` locally.  AWS Lambda use `v0.10.36`, indeed you can test locally.

Comment: @Nori I have update the answer for the content is too long for a comment

Comment: Oh... I don't know that AWS Lambda is retained the permission. I added the read permission to the PNG file, so I have solved the problem. Thanks a lot!